# How to get access to the right nodes?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph, force-layout

i use the d3.js force layout and i am able to click on a startnode and a endnote and the code below higlights all nodes between. The code binds a JSON file in hierarchy.

My next idea is, to show up a text, that makes clear which nodes where highlighted in the right order.
That means:

```
"first node:" name of the first node ,
"second node:" name of the second node,
"third node:" name of the third node,

.....
"end node:" name of the end node
```

But at this point, i am only able show up only the name of the node i am clicking on directly (d.data.name).
startNode.path(d) is a funcion which returns the shortest way of "startNode" and "d".
Before clicking anything it always shows the text: "first node: null" . My question is: how can i get access to the nodes between the start node and the end node?

```
    var startNode = null;


                    var node = svg.append("g")
                      .
                      .
                      .
                          .on("click", function(d, i) 
                          {
                            var path1 = startNode && startNode.path(d) || []; 
                            startNode = d;

                            node.attr("r", function(d) 
                            {
                              return path1.includes(d) || startNode == d ? 8 : 3;     

                            });

textNode.text("first node: " + d.data.name);
                          })

                  var textNode = svg.append("text")
            .attr("dx", 112)
            .attr("dy", 490)
            .text("first node: " + startNode)
```

Comment: My plan is maybe to store them in an extra array...but i don't know if that is the right idea and where to start.